DAX calculate monthly frequency
I'm trying to calculate amount of month from Table FACTS in selected ( via SSAS Excel) period in which there is at least 1 occurance per month of SubGroupId. So basically it's called monthy frequency.
Structure that I have: Dim table



ID
SubGroupId
Group




1
1
A


2
2
A


3
3
A


4
4
B


5
5
B


6
6
B



Fact table



RowId
DimId
Date




1
1
01.01.2024


2
1
01.01.2024


3
2
01.02.2024


4
3
01.03.2024


5
4
01.04.2024


6
5
01.05.2024


7
6
01.06.2024



So i need to create a measure which counts these amounts of month for each [SubGroupId]. It works correctly with measure that I created
CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT('Calendar'[YYYYMMKey])
         , 'Facts'
         , 'Facts'[DimId] <> 0)
         )

And I am getting this result



Group
MonthFreq




A
2


B
1






Group
SubGroup
MonthFreq




A
1
2



2
1



3
1


B
4
1



5
1



6
1



Here I can see, that Measure counts distinct amount of month in period by linking Group, instead of counting sum of occurance of subgroup.
Simply speaking here's result I'm trying to get



Group
MonthFreq




A
4


B
3






Group
SubGroup
MonthFreq




A
1
2



2
1



3
1


B
4
1



5
1



6
1



So if I select only Group without division by SubGroup then I need to see SUM(amount of unique months for every subgroup, which Id was in FACT table)
Thanks in advance for any help

Please don't use images for data. Use table markdown.

@DaleK, sry, fixed

What are your relationships?

You can create relationship between Dimid and ID column

then you can use measure
= count([date])

or you even don't need to create a measure

